# Filter by type of content into specific content

Tags: mobile, filter, tab

I have some trouble to find a UX pattern that would fit for an mobile app improvement.

I would like to display in the news feed a filter by type of content for example:
News, Event, Project etc…
+ Search bar

(similar to [this one](https://scdn.androidcommunity.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Photo-29-05-2017-11-29-14-AM-1068x801.jpg))

Moreover I would like to also include this filter + search into specific type of content.

For example, Project can embed (News + Event). So I want to be able to filter News and Event inside "Project".

The problem is that in my "project" I also want to show a lot of information about the project and I'm not sure it's a good solution to put the tab bar at the bottom of the infos. Also, I can't put the filter at the top of my project because it will make no sense to show content before project info.

The main goal is to have quick access to content inside the project and be able to filter it, but also have a quick view of my project info.

What pattern would be the best? Do you have a similar case to show?

I imagine it to be similar to this screen, except I should also be able to filter content into each tab.

[image: enter link description here]

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the "progressive disclosure" principle. First, you want the user to find items that are tagged news, event, project etc. You can do this by adding a filtering pattern with checkboxes for each type of tag.

Secondly, begin by revealing the most important facts about each item in the search results. If you add too much info for each item in the search results you risk getting crowded and messy screen. Provide basic information, the user taps on it and then more relevant information is presented.